# GET Request from Arduino to Lua (ESP8266)

Tags: lua, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a problem with my GET request. ESP8266 with NodeMCU. My code in Arduino:

```
String cmd = "conn:send(\"GET /json.htm?type=command&param=udevice&idx=2&nvalue=0&svalue=11 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.0.101\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n\")";
wifi.println("conn=nil");
wifi.println("conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)");
wifi.println("conn:on(\"receive\", function(conn, payload) print(payload) end)");
wifi.println("conn:connect(8080, \"192.168.0.101\")");
wifi.println(cmd);
```

Error:

> ")stdin:1: unfinished string near '"GET /json.htm?type=command&param=udevice&idx=2&nvalue=0&svalue=11 HTTP/1.1Host: 192'

Doesn't Lua see `\r\n` in GET requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use double `\\` instead, depending on where you are using it (Send box for example).

And since you are using `\"` to escape the quotes, `\\n` should probably do it.