# GET request failed in Arduino-Uno

Tags: wifi, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I am trying to access a simple web page running in my Rpi-server using ESP8266 and Arduino.

I have refereed [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568769/get-request-from-arduino-to-lua-esp8266) , but it's not the solution for my problem.

Here is my current Arduino Code :

```
#include "WiFiEsp.h"

// Emulate Serial1 on pins 6/7 if not present
#ifndef HAVE_HWSERIAL1
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(2,3); // RX, TX
#endif

char ssid[] = "RPi";            // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "raspberry";        // your network password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the Wifi radio's status

char server[] = "192.168.50.1";

// Initialize the Ethernet client object
WiFiEspClient client;

void setup()
{
  // initialize serial for debugging
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize serial for ESP module
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  // initialize ESP module
  WiFi.init(&Serial1);

  // check for the presence of the shield
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data
  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  
  printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request
    client.println("GET /simple.html  HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.50.1");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
}

void loop()
{

  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Disconnecting from server...");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore
    while (true);
  }

void printWifiStatus()
{
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("Signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting connection to server...
[WiFiEsp] Connecting to 192.168.50.1
Connected to server
[WiFiEsp] Data packet send error (2)
[WiFiEsp] Failed to write to socket 3
[WiFiEsp] Disconnecting  3
```

My `simple.html` looks like this.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <p>1</p>

    </body>
</html>

}
```

I accessed to this page from web browser and it shows the content properly.
What is missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: has the esp8266 strong enough power supply? 3.3V pin on Arduino can't supply necessary Amps for WiFi data send

Answer (score 2):

Try this line in your code

```
client.print("GET /simple.html  HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
```